# Randomly pick one distinct row of every group?

Tags: sql, oracle, random, greatest-n-per-group

Let say I have this SQL in Oracle :

```
 select field1,field2 from table where field2 in (32,421,5766) and .....
```

it normally will return many rows.
How do I pick 3 random rows ONE from every group that is defined by field2 and also match the rest of the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and give the rows a random order:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2
FROM   (
  SELECT field1,
         field2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY field2 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() )
           AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  field2 IN (32, 421, 5766)
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( field1, field2 ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,    1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL,   32 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL,  421 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL, 5766 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

May (randomly) output:

> ```
> FIELD1 | FIELD2
> -----: | -----:
>      3 |     32
>      6 |    421
>      7 |   5766
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22f09cea7d3a7e7707e43da891c9a161)*